# vala: manipulating (gstreamer) GLib.Value

Tags: gstreamer, vala

I've written the small vala program below, and I don't know how
to manipulate the GLib.Value types, see the code below :

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-level.html

```
using Gst;


void application_message(Gst.Bus bus, Gst.Message msg) {

        var s = msg.get_structure();

        if(s == null)
            return;

        string msgtype = s.get_name();

        if(msgtype != "level")
            return;
                
        GLib.Value rms = s.get_value("rms");
        GLib.Value st = s.get_value("stream-time");

        // according to the doc here : http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-level.html

        // "rms" is apparently a  "GValueArray of gdouble"
        // and         
        // "st" is a GstClockTime, which is a "typedef guint64 GstClockTime"

        // I want to create a string representation of the two, ex: 

        // 72374237490234, [0.234234,0,424234234,0.423423423,0.5345345, ...]

        // and I'm clueless as to how to do the conversions or typecasts...
}


void main (string[] args) {

    Gst.init (ref args);

    try {

        var pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
          "pulsesrc device=\"alsa_input.usb-046d_08c9_674634A4-02-U0x46d0x8c9.analog-mono\" ! " +
          "level name=wavelevel interval=10000000 ! " +
          "wavenc ! filesink location=audioz.wav"
        );

        var bus = pipeline.get_bus();

        bus.add_signal_watch();
        bus.message.connect(application_message);

        // Set pipeline state to PLAYING
        pipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);

        // Creating and starting a GLib main loop
        new MainLoop ().run ();        
    }
    catch(Error e) {
        print("%s\n", e.message);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE :

THe doc for GLib.Value is here : http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gobject-2.0/GLib.Value

calling strdup_contents() is somewhat satisfactory, but I'd like to manipulate the array in rms,

printl(rms.type().name()) tells me that it's a GstValueList,
so I'd thing that I should cast it to this :
http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gstreamer-1.0/Gst.ValueList
but vala seems to know nothing of the type Gst.ValueList...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vala makes working with GLib.Value very easy, it will implicitly convert between GLib.Value and the native types.  Throwing GLib.StringBuilder into the mix to build your array, something like this (untested) should do the trick:

```
GLib.StringBuilder s = new GLib.StringBuilder ();

s.append (((uint64) st).to_string ());
s.append (",[");
{
  bool first = true;
  foreach ( unowned GLib.Value value in rms.values ) {
    if (!first) {
      s.append_c (',');
    } else {
      first = false;
    }
    s.append (((double) value).to_string ());
  }
}
s.append_c (']');
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer. If you don't mind here's another one : how could I declare an array of int local variable, and access the value with indexes (suppose I know that the array is always of size 2 and I just want to obtain the two uint64) ?

Comment: By "array", do you mean a standard array or GLib.ValueArray?

Comment: The real need is to extract the values in the array by constant index, something like : uint64 x1 = rms.values(0).get_uint64. I don't really care if it's an array or a collection type supporting access by index.

Comment: It seems that the .values does not exist, I get :  gstpipe.vala:32.32-32.41: error: The name `values' does not exist in the context of `GLib.Value'
        uint64 rms1 = (uint64) rms.values[0];

Comment: `values` is a member of GLib.ValueArray, but you're whatever that error message is about is a GLib.Value, not a GLib.ArrayValue.  If you want to pastebin a test case I can take a look.  Also, instead of putting small questions like this here, you might want to consider dropping by #vala on irc.gnome.org.

Comment: Line 72 on this pastebin : http://pastebin.com/WWJfTNYr msg.get_structure().get_value("rms") returns a GLib.Value type, I have n't found in the docs how to get the rms as an ArrayValue...

Comment: In that code you have rms as a GLib.Value not a GLib.ValueArray.  There is an example of unboxing a GLib.Value to a double in my example above, a GLib.ValueArray would be much the same; replace line 57 with `GLib.ValueArray rms = (GLib.ValueArray) s.get_value("rms");`

Comment: Compiler says : error: duplicating ValueArray instance, use unowned variable or explicitly invoke copy method. If a prefix the declaration with unowned or weak, it compiles fine, but gives me a segmentation fault when I call rms.values[0], or rms.get_nth(0)...